# The code block below execute before my async await finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```js
const getGroup = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  try {
    const group = await Group.findOne({ _id: id });    
    const groupNotesPromise = await group.group_notes.map( async (fileId) => {
      const file = await File.findById(fileId)
      return file;
    })
    const groupNotes = await groupNotesPromise.map( async (notePromise) => {
      await notePromise.then(res => console.log(res))
    })
    console.log(groupNotes)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(err.message);
    res.status(400).json({ err: err.message });
  }
}
```

Hello guys, I have a function above, this is retrieving data from MongoDB.

However, I would like to know why would my `console.log(groupNotes)` be printed before the execution of the `groupNotesPromise.map` above, as it has an `await` in the function.

Below is the `console.log(groupNotes)` and `console.log(res)` from the code above

```js
[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6496c645bf2bb491b931f082"),
  fileName: 'test',
  fileAwsReference: 'b4b71d06828d23d857b3611c2ce2480cf704f1fc1b9cb1879b563159631d162a',
  createdBy: new ObjectId("648bab3c8044efccc461ad1d"),
  createdIn: new ObjectId("648d7776284835591f536552"),
  __v: 0
},
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6496c9fafb91e60683fc812d"),
  fileName: 'waeewaea',
  fileAwsReference: '0e1f17f127f9a12a9e27d765bda1436297f0d58eb7d20f3e9dc8d39e64b58c5b',
  createdBy: new ObjectId("648bab3c8044efccc461ad1d"),
  createdIn: new ObjectId("648d7776284835591f536552"),
  __v: 0
}
```